# Using socket module in website integrated python 3 IDE

Tags: python-3.x, sockets

```
import socket
a = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
print(a)
```

When I run this code in the IDE in my pc, it shows the Ipv4 address of my pc.

But when I run this code in the integrated IDE in sololearn, it shows some other Ipv4 address but not mine. How to modify the code to show the Ip address of the user and not the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
socket.gethostname()
```

> Return a string containing the hostname of the machine where the
>   Python interpreter is currently executing.
>
> Note: gethostname() doesn’t always return the fully qualified domain
>   name; use getfqdn() for that.

I've never heard of sololearn, but the python documentation is crystal clear on this one. It's possible your local name resolver is configured strangely, but that is beyond the scope of this question.

Comment: Sir, sololearn is a learning site like codeacademy, where they have an python ide integrated to the site. I want to run a python code in that ide in the site to get the ip address of my pc. But when i use gethostname or getfqdn, I get ip address of the site's server but not mine. Im new to programming, please help me.

Comment: If you want your ip address then run code on your computer.

Comment: I run it in my computer only, but in the ide present in that website. Is there any solution?